# C Program terminated only after it has executed in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I intentionally made an out of bound index access in my program which is given below :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[1];

    x[1] = 3; // expected SIGABRT here
    printf("x[1] = %d\n",x[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

But my program got terminated only after the execution of the line where I was expecting a abort. The same happened when I debugged. Find the output below.

```
x[1] = 3
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I know that C doesn't have out of bound checking feature. My question is why it didn't terminate after the execution of x[1] = 3 without going for the next statement ?

Comment: C is a native language and allows you to access arrays outside its bounds without checking. But it will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LM358 why I'm getting an abort after the program has executed ?

Comment: Why not after the program has executed?  There's no compulsion that the program crashes.  There's no compulsion that it doesn't crash.  You've invoked undefined behaviour; that means there's no reliable way to predict what result will happen. The crash probably occurs as the return code from `main()` checks on its stack and spots your stack smashing.  Replace `return 0;` with `exit(0);` (and `#include <stdlib.h>`, of course), and you might not get any error at all — or you might still get caught; that's the beauty of undefined behaviour. Anything can happen, and it is OK — undefined behaviour.

Comment: *I know that C doesn't have out of bound checking feature. My question is why it didn't terminate [sooner]?* The question appears at odds with the statement preceding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that this is about using a canary value to detect attempts of exploiting a stack buffer overflow.

The stack (aka the canary value) isn't checked until the function returns. Therefore you'll get the `printf` executed first and then the stack check is performed.

In other words, the "out of bounds" access isn't detected the moment it happens. So the program carries on until the function returns.

You could put the offending code into a function like:

```
void foo()
{
    int x[1];

    x[1] = 3; // expected SIGABRT here
    printf("x[1] = %d\n",x[1]);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    printf("Back in main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

to see if the program terminates before printing "Back in main"